# Customize Wordpress (WP) themes in a docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, themes

Could you please point me to a right direction:
**Description**:
I wanted to modify a WP theme using dockerized WP.
I could edit the theme (`Appearance > Theme Editor`) then edit the `*.php` file.
Yet, I could not `Update File`. There is the following error:

```
Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.
```

**I tried**:

- Deactivate/re-activate all plugins (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671255/wordpress-editor-not-updating-files-unable-to-communicate-back-with-site-to-che/56669347)), but the error persisted.

Thanks in advance for your kind helps.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a Docker volume for the image.

Then it is possible to inspect the volume and edit the files directly (i.e. via VSCode).

The path to the theme files is `wp-content/themes/..`